# Optimal way to get counts from matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm looking to optimize (readability, speed) the following code, which simulates a draft based on assigned probabilities and then counts the occurrences of each unique value in each row of a matrix:

```
# toy example values
random_probs <- rbeta(26, 10, 20)
random_probs <- random_probs/sum(random_probs)
player_names <- letters

draft_simulations <- 
  replicate(1000, sample(1:26, 26, replace = FALSE, prob = random_probs)) %>%
  matrix(., nrow = 26, ncol = 1000)

list_sims <- map(1:26, ~rowSums(draft_simulations == .))

as_tibble(do.call(rbind, list_sims)) %>%
  mutate(Skater = player_names) %>%
  select(Skater, everything())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

I think you have two main options about the logic behind the problem:

1. For each **option** o in 1-26, build an index matrix `draft_simulations == o`, then `rowSums` it;
2. For each **player** p in 1-26, table its row `table(draft_simulations[p,])`.

On top of that choice, I'd say you have two main possible efficiency gains:

1. Use better functions;
2. Use a better looping structure.

**Better functions**

For (1.) I think `rowSums` and `==` are about as good as it gets. But for `table`, there are a lot of different options, as you can see on [Is there an efficient alternative to table()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68604367/is-there-an-efficient-alternative-to-table). I'd recommend reading all the answers to that question,  as each have their pros and cons, but here, I'll stick to `base::tabulate`.

**Better looping structure**

You have for loops, the `base::apply` family, and `purrr::map`. Is not obvious which to use, so I'll test below.

### Testing

I tested options using `rowSums`, `table`, and `tabulate`, with all the looping options (code at the end), which yielded:

```
bench::mark(rowsums_for(), rowsums_sapply(), rowsums_map(),
            table_for(), table_apply(),
            tabulate_for(), tabulate_apply(),
            check = FALSE, min_time = 1) %>%
  select(expression:`gc/sec`)

  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
1 rowsums_for()      3.08ms      4ms      260.    2.59MB     9.04
2 rowsums_sapply()   3.14ms   4.13ms      251.     2.6MB     9.02
3 rowsums_map()      3.27ms    4.3ms      241.    2.59MB     9.01
4 table_for()        4.41ms   4.73ms      208.    1.87MB     5.33
5 table_apply()      4.59ms   4.96ms      200.    1.98MB     5.33
6 tabulate_for()    231.2µs  250.7µs     3788.  210.94KB    11.9 
7 tabulate_apply()  289.2µs    311µs     3090.   312.8KB    11.9
```

So, at least for the dimension of your problem, for loops are better. Also, `rowSums` is better than `table`, but `tabulate` is the clear winner. This isn't necessarily true if the dimensions are different.

**Functions:**

```
plays <- 26
players <- 26
n_sims <- 1000

random_probs <- rbeta(plays, 10, 20)
random_probs <- random_probs/sum(random_probs)

draft_simulations <-
  replicate(n_sims, sample(1:plays, players, replace = FALSE, prob = random_probs)) %>%
  matrix(nrow = players, ncol = n_sims)


rowsums_for <- function(){
  result <- matrix(nrow = players, ncol = plays)
  for(i in 1:plays){
    result[,i] <- rowSums(draft_simulations == i)
  }
}

rowsums_sapply <- function(){
  sapply(1:players, function(x) rowSums(draft_simulations == x))
}

rowsums_map <- function(){
  map(1:players, ~ rowSums(draft_simulations == .x))
}

table_for <- function(){
  result <- matrix(nrow = players, ncol = plays)
  for(i in 1:players){
    result[i,] <- table(draft_simulations[i,])
  }
}

table_apply <- function(){
  apply(draft_simulations, 1, table)
}

tabulate_for <- function(){
  result <- matrix(nrow = players, ncol = plays)
  for(i in 1:players){
    result[i,] <- tabulate(draft_simulations[i,])
  }
}

tabulate_apply <- function(){
  apply(draft_simulations, 1, tabulate)
}
```

Comment: What a thoughtful, informative and enriching answer. Thank you so much Ricardo!